# Restart service after RPM transaction

Tags: centos, systemd, rpm, rpm-spec

I have an RPM package which updates a config file and so entails a restart of that service (rsyslog). My supported platforms include a pre-systemd version (centos6) and systemd versions (centos7+). My question is what is the best way to check for the existence of systemd and where to run this post update restart task? From what I can tell, this should suffice:

```
%posttrans
if test pidof systemd = 1; then
    systemctl restart rsyslog
else
    service restart rsyslog
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `service` can use `systemctl` when it is available. It will print a notification about redirecting to /bin/systemctl and you can safely ignore it. You can therefore use:

   ```
   %posttrans
   service rsyslog restart
   ```

Mind that the correct order is different than you used in your question.

2. Or you can use %rhel macro.

   ```
   %posttrans
   %if 0%{rhel} >=7
      systemctl restart rsyslog
   %else
      service rsyslog restart
   %endif
   ```

But this is evaluated in build time. So you have to have one binary package for EL6 and second for EL7+.